# CakePHP CakeDC user plugin permision not working

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I have a problem that the "`cakeDC users`" plugin does not work with the `bypassAuth` that I would get an example of how it should be implemented.

my code:

```
return [
'CakeDC/Auth.permissions' => [
     [
       'controller' => 'test',
      'action' => ['index'],
      'bypassAuth' => 'true',
    ],....
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `'bypassAuth' => true` as the expected type is boolean|null, not string.